# EJS what are the rules for breaking up statements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

**Question:** When using EJS templates what are the rules for breaking up statements in Javascript?  Most of the time avoiding compiling errors in EJS is easy but sometimes they happen unexpectedly.

**Background:** The following examples use a simple Node.js route that sends an array to *index.ejs* to be rendered.

**app.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    let catArray = ['whiskers', 'socks', 'psycho'];
    res.render('index', { catArray });
});
```

The following works as expected without error.

**index.ejs**

```
    <% catArray.forEach( function(element) { %> 
        <div><%= element %></div>
    <% }); %>
```

However when I break the line at a different location it throws an error.

```
    <% catArray.forEach( %> 
        <% function(element) { %> 
        <div><%= element %></div>
    <% }); %>
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in C:\fileLocation\index.ejs while
>   compiling ejs

In the next example I use a Promise.  This is not something I would normally do in an EJS template but it works as an example.

The code below works as expected without error.

**index.ejs**

```
    <% new Promise(promiseExecutor).then(randomLogic).catch(failed); %>

    <% function promiseExecutor(resolve, reject) {
        let randomNumber = 10;
        if(randomNumber < 5) {
            reject('number is less than 5');
        } else {
            resolve('number is greater than 5');
        }
    } %>

    <% function randomLogic(message) {
        console.log('success, ', message);
    } %>

    <% function failed(message) {
        console.log('failure, ', message);
    } %>
```

However when I break the first line up into 3 lines it throws an error.

**index.ejs**

```
    <% new Promise(promiseExecutor) %>
    <% .then(randomLogic) %>
    <% .catch(failed); %>
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in C:\fileLocation\index.ejs while
>   compiling ejs

I'm sure there are other examples but these are two I recently ran across.

Comment: Once you start putting logic inside a template, restart your project completely; nothing good will happen from then on

Comment: It's pretty simple actually. Think of every `%> … <%` as a `templateOutput.append(" … ")` statement (and every `<%= … %>`  inside that as a `"+( … )+"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when EJS is compiled it adds a `;` every time it sees an ending `%>` that is part of a non-output code block.  If the added `;` would throw an error in normal JavaScript it will also throw an error in EJS.

This statement...

```
<% catArray.forEach( function(element) { %> 
<% }); %>
```

...becomes this statement which DOES NOT throw an error in EJS or regular JS.

```
catArray.forEach( function(element) {;  // semicolon here is ok
});; // extra semicolon here is fine
```

However this statement...

```
<% catArray.forEach( %> 
<% function(element) { %> 
<% }); %>
```

...becomes this statement which DOES throw an error in EJS and regular JS.

```
catArray.forEach(; // semicolon here throws error
function(element) {;  // semicolon here is ok
});; // extra semicolon here is fine
```

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the EJS documentation, see -> [Line Breaks Inside a tag](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/master/docs/syntax.md#line-breaks-inside-a-tag)

> Line breaks are allowed in <% tags.
>
> Unless the statement involves mixing EJS and JavaScript scriptlet,
>   always put complete statements in a tag. For example, the following
>   works:
>
> ```
> <% var stringToShow = thisIsABooleanVariableWithAVeryLongName
>                     ? 'OK'
>                     : 'not OK' %>
> ```
>
> While the following does not:
>
> ```
> <% var stringToShow = thisIsABooleanVariableWithAVeryLongName %>
> <%                  ? 'OK'                                    %>
> <%                  : 'not OK'                                %>
> ```

Comment: `<% }); %>` is not a complete statement. I don't think this answers the question really, at least not entirely.

Comment: @AlexWayne your comment may have helped me figure this out.  It looks like `%>` tells the compiler to add a `;`.  If the added `;` would cause an error in normal javascript it causes an error in EJS.  Adding an extra `;` to `<% }); %>` doesn't cause an error in normal Javascript or EJS.